# ORACLE find first non-null value from history table

Tags: oracle, notnull

I have a history table where I want to return ONLY the first `STATUS` value which is not null (if any). I haven't got much ORACLE experience and I have searched for this but couldn't find anything I need.

***EDIT***
Example of my table below.

```
ITEM   NAME   STATUS
Item1  Test1  Null
Item1  Test2  Null
Item1  Test3  Approved
Item2  Test1  Null
Item2  Test2  Approved
```

In the example above, I would ONLY like to return the following rows.

```
Item1 Test3 Approved
Item2 Test2 Approved
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have some implicit ordering in your sample output, and you should have included this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mean:  For each value of item, order the rows with non-NULL status by name and take the first one.  If that's correct:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    item, name, status,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY name) AS rn
  FROM t
  WHERE status is NOT NULL
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what you mean by "first" (ordered how?), so this will do:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE status IS NOT NULL
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my initial question. I would like the first `STATUS` value that is not null to be returned for all items in the table. I have also edited my example.

Answer (score 0):

By referring @WW's answer, If you wanted to return all items then only modify following (i.e. remove `rownum` condition)

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
```